ALB redirect to https not working behind NLB
I have an NLB and as a target group, I am specifying ALB. My HTTPS connection works fine, but HTTP doesn't work.  In ALB I have a rule to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS
HTTPS://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}

But if I am trying to access through NLB, redirection is not happening.
NLB has two target groups. 1st redirects to the ALB on port 443, 2nd redirects to the ALB on port 80.
I need NLB as my domain registration requires A address, so static IP.
Any ideas how I can fix the problem?

Please add your NLB configuration to your question. My guess is the NLB is only forwarding to the HTTPS listener on the ALB, so the HTTP listener's redirect rule never gets invoked.
